# Why do operations I perform on a copied multi-level array affect the original array?

Tags: python, arrays, debugging

For example, if I had a list

```
t = [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
```

and I copied it and changed element [1][1] to "z" like this

```
t2 = t.copy()
t2[1][1] = "z"
```

when I print both tables, only t2 should be changed but the original table is affected as well, why is this? I'm not sure if this questions has been asked before so I apologize if this is a repeated question but I've been having trouble understanding this. Thanks.

Comment: `.copy` is shallow.

Answer (score 1):

`copy` performs a **shallow** copy - i.e., you get a new "outer" list that points to the same "inner" lists the original points to. If this is not the desired behavior, you could use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) instead:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> t = [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
>>> t2 = deepcopy(t)
>>> t2[1][1] = "z"
>>> t
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
>>> t2
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'z', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, `copy()` does a shallow copy, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original.

So in your example, `t2[1]=["j","j","j"]` will not affect t, but if you want to go to the next level, you need to to a deep copy

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a deep copy. Try this:

```
import copy
t = [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h","i"]]
t2 = copy.deepcopy(t)
t2[1][1] = "z"
```

Now t should have its original constents, while the copy in t2 got affected by the change requested